# Erro HRESULT:0x80020003 no sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

Estou trabalhando com um banco de dados Sql server e ele começou a apresentar um erro estranho, me impedindo de acessar o design e de criar novas tables. Procurei na internet e não consegui resolver esse erro.

Comment: Tem mais contexto?

Comment: infelizmente isso é tudo que eu sei, esse erro literalmente apareceu do nada

Comment: ele diz apenas Membro não encontrado, não  só neste banco, mas para todos q eu conecto.

Comment: Você está acessando o SQL pelo VS? Tem como postar uma imagem do erro ocorrendo?